# One socket, multiple http request, different Host header but server returns cached Host header

Tags: java, http, servlets

I am using a custom servlet engine of a vendor product. Our server are fronted by different proxy with different host names. Assuming the host names are `host1.localhost.com` and  `host2.localhost.com`.

We have following servlet

```
public class MyServlet {

    public void doGet(...) {

             response.getOutputStream.write(request.getServerName().getBytes())
} }
```

We encountered an issue that some times if we make a request `host1.localhost.com/my/servlet` we see actually see `host2.localhost.com/my/servlet` in the response.

Decompiling vendor product's code revealed that their servlet engine caches the Host header as long as the socket is kept alive.

In attempt to reproduce the problem I wrote some low level socket code to make HTTP requests:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("host2.localhost.com", 8080));
OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();

/*this thread keeps printing stuff in the input stream*/
Thread t = new ResponsePrintThread(s.getInputStream());
t.start()

os.write("GET /my/servlet/testservlet HTTP/1.1\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("Host: 12345\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
os.flush();

os.write("GET /my/serlet/testservlet HTTP/1.1\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("Host: 7891011\r\n".getBytes());
os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
os.flush();
```

The above will print

```
12345
12345
```

But I would expect

```
12345
7891011
```

My question is, does the servlet engine behave correctly by caching and returning the same host header for the same socket connection, or should it re-parse the HTTP headers and update the cached host header? My Thinking is that since HTTP suppose to be stateless, so any information in the HTTP request should be re-parsed and reloaded, even the host header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is a little vague on how connections are made between client and server:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-22#section-6.2

> It is beyond the scope of this specification to describe how
> connections are established via various transport or session-layer
> protocols.

I don't see anything wrong if a client uses one persistent connection for two host names that resolve to the same IP. It ought not to cause any problem on the server side.